# How to pass an enumeration as a parameter to a function?

Tags: java, function, parameter-passing, enumeration, strong-typing

Is there a clean way of passing an enumeration CLASS to a function?

Consider something like this:

```
public enum MyEnum implements XYZ {

   //enum values
   A,
   B,
   C;
}

public void getEnumeration(final Class<? extends XYZ> myEnum) {

   //go through enumeration
   for (XYZ xyz : myEnum.getEnumConstants()
       System.out.println(xyz.toString());
}
```

enumeration passed in as follows:

```
getFunction(MyEnum.class);
```

now... the above works and I can pass my enumeration to the `getEnumeration()` function just fine. HOWEVER, I'd like to ensure that what I am passing in is indeed an enumeration and not any class that implements `XYZ`. **I realize that enumeration is a type of class**, but is there a way to strong type this such that the compiler would pick it up if I pass in a class that implement `XYZ` instead of enumeration that implements `XYZ`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
public static <T extends Enum<T> & XYZ> void getEnumeration(Class<T> myEnum) {
    // ...
}
```

Here's an actual example I wrote to test out my concept:

```
public class EnumTest {
    public enum Runnables implements Runnable {
        HELLO {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.print("Hello, ");
            }
        },
        WORLD {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("world!");
            }
        };
    }

    public static <T extends Enum<T> & Runnable> void getEnumeration(Class<T> myEnum) {
        for (Runnable runnable : myEnum.getEnumConstants())
            runnable.run();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getEnumeration(Runnables.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, wasn't aware I could use the "&" in templating... now, I tried your idea with my code and have a question. I have to store the passed in enumeration in my class. So will my variable be something like: `private myVar Class<? extends Enum<? extends XYZ>>` ? I am not sure how to use templates for variables...

Comment: Parameterise your class on that type: e.g., `public class MyClass<T extends Enum<T> & XYZ>`. Then just use `private Class<T> myVar;`.